# Is there a way to detect if the user clicks on the right or left side of the Apple tv remote?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

I can detect press by overriding `pressesEnded` method, but how can I find if user pressed on the right or the left side of the remote?

Answer (score 1):

Directional taps can be detected inspecting the press type:

```
    override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        for press in presses {
            switch press.type {
            case .upArrow:
                print("⬆️")
            case .downArrow:
                print("⬇️")
            default:
                super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
            }
        }
    }
```

Directional clicks, on the other hand, requires the use of the GameControler SDK, you can find it explained here: https://medium.com/@dcordero/directional-clicks-on-tvos-c711a2faf71a

Comment: This seems doesn't work anymore, I tried to run your project on my local but it always return at guard let controller = GCController.controllers().first else { return }